# How to draw a line on a surface view using ffmpeg or OpenGL on playing video in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i.e In golf match, when ball hit by player at that time they display line from starting and ending points over video.

see attached image for same:

[image: Image for line over running video]

Comment: does it fit in you scenario to add the line before it starts and then when video starts playing it will show at the time of your choice?

Comment: yes. It is also work